# Translate animation behind objects

Tags: android, animation

I have a problem with a translate animation.
I want the animation takes place above all other objects, and in my case the animated object moves behind other objects.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: user2211439 can you please mark the question as answered if my answer was helpful?

Answer (score 3):

Move the View to the front before animating.  Example:

```
private void startTranslateAnimation(View v, TranslateAnimation ta)
{
    v.bringToFront();
    v.startAnimation(ta);
}
```